# Difference between simplicial complex and underlying space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

An underlying space $|K|$ is the subset of $R^n$ which is the union of the simplices of $K$. While a simplicial complex $K$ is a collection of simplices s.t. every face of its simplex is in $K$ and the intersection of any two simplexes is a face of each of them.

My question is, why do I need the underlying space if I have a simplicial complex $K$. What's the difference between them? Could anyone give an explanation and examples (with a picture if possible). Thank you!

Comment: In order to draw a picture of a simplicial complex, you need to know the underlying topological space since this is exactly what you're drawing. The simplicial complex itself is just a collection of sets.

Comment: I read in wikipeda. Suppose that I have a simplicial 3-complex $K$ like this <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_complex#/media/File:Simplicial_complex_example.svg> So what is my $|K|$?

Comment: An important thing to include is the function from the simplical complex to the original space, without it they are not relatable. The function itself is crucial and that it is continuous.

Comment: @ZelosMalum, what do you mean?

Comment: There is always a morphism/function that ties the simplical complex to a topological space. A simplical complex and a space $K$ have no relation, they are independed and distinct, unless you can find some function between them, of course in topology it must always be continuous

Comment: @ZelosMalum. In idea of simplicial complex (in wikipedia) is: a simplicial complex is a "topological space" of a certain kind, constructed by the union of points, line segments, triangles, and their n-dimensional counterparts.

Comment: @ZelosMalum, what's the correlation of your statement with the underlying space?

Comment: When the wikipedia article says "simplicial complex" in the introduction, it actually refers to the underlying space of the simplicial complex. Read the definition in the article. A simplicial complex with two $1$-simplices $\sigma,\tau$ having vertices $x,y,z$ (that means they share one vertex) is the set $\{\sigma,\tau,x,y,z\}$, while the underlying space is $\sigma\cup\tau$.

Comment: @Stefan. Oh I see... OK. I understand now the difference. Thanks again, Stefan!